# Can I skip query parameters?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, post, axios

I am trying to make a post request with 3 query parameters:

```
axios.post(`http://localhost:4000/items?q1=val1&q2=val2&q3=val3)
```

however, my question is that is there any way to skip a query value? If I didn't want to input the value of q3, how can I implement that?

In the post controller, the value is taken from query in such a way that the number of queries in it wouldn't matter. If I manually, add or remove a query from the request, it works fine, but I was wondering if there's another way to do this because I input my values from a form and if one of the inputs is left blank, can I still make a post request skipping that query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your node script you can use this code to get all query in a dynamic way:

```
let queryObject = request.get();
```

in this way you will have all query string params in this object and you can use it to do your logic, Example: if we have the first param and not the second do something otherwise if we have the second param and not the first do other things:

```
if(!!queryObject.q1 && !queryOnject.q2){
   //do something
}
else if(!queryObject.q1 && !!queryOnject.q2){
   //do something
}
else if(!!queryObject.q3){
   //do something
}
else {
    response.status(400).send("bad request");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is your server framework/technology?

In NodeJS, you can simply do ..

```
let { query1, query2 , query3} = request.get(); // or whatever is supported in your server
```

..or for any number of params:

```
let queries = request.get();
// iterate through query as an object. 
// e.g Object.keys(queries).forEach((prop) => console.log(prop));
```